# curl not getting response when run from script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, soap

I have simple bash script wrapping curl in order to read message and header from file, then build curl command, execute it and read the response.

Script also prints out the full command being run. When I run this printed command directly from shell I get expected response, but when it's run inside the script the response is empty.

Is there any secret behavior change for curl while run inside script?

**command generated:**

```
curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://soap.xxxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz"' --data-ascii '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap (...) full message xml</soap:Envelope>' http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/yyyyy/zzzzz
```

**script snippet**

```
cmdline='curl -s '
if [[ -n $header ]]
then
  cmdline="$cmdline -H '$header'"
fi
if [[ -n $message ]]
then
  cmdline=$cmdline" --data-ascii '"$message"'"
fi

cmdline="$cmdline $target"

echo $cmdline

response=$($cmdline)

echo response:
echo $response
echo EOF
```

I tried redirecting response to file using --output switch but no file was generated. Like I said - works from shell, no response from script

Comment: You can debug your script by including `set -xv` in the section where you want to see what the script is doing. It's more reliable than using `echo` commands.

Comment: This was helpful. Bash has escaped the crap out of this envelope so no wonder it's not working. I guess my workaround is not as ugly way of dealing with this than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why the original script is not working, but I found a workaround. I still generate curl command but instead of running it I dump it into file and then run this file.

```
tmpscr=/tmp/runws_$(date +%s).sh
echo $cmdline > $tmpscr
chmod +x $tmpscr
response=$($tmpscr)
rm $tmpscr
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is not reproduced, following test is ok:

```
$ cat prueba.sh 
target=www.google.com

...your script.

$ ./prueba.sh 

curl -s www.google.com

response:
... the html answer
EOF
```

*** Second test also pass ***

```
$ cat prueba.sh 
message='<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap (...) full message xml</soap:Envelope>'
header='http://soap.xxxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz'
target=www.google.com

... remainder script

$ ./prueba.sh 
curl -s -H 'http://soap.xxxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz' --data-ascii '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap (...) full message xml</soap:Envelope>' www.google.com
response:
...html
```

Comment: I think the clue to the problem is including soap envelope in request. Simple request without $message value set works for me as well.

Comment: Usual suspicious are symbols < and >. Could you add to the original question the test done? init of values and output.

Comment: I can't, it has too much confidential corporate stuff. I used set -xv like Anthony suggested - bash has escaped the crap out of this envelope, no wonder it's not working.